# Arguments in defenition

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, arguments

I am programming an application with tkinter (Canvas) and I have a problem with the arguments.

```
def printsomething(argument, event):
    print(argument)

c.tag_bind(button,'<Button-1>', printsomething('text'))
```

The problem is that I have to keep the 'event', otherwise it's executed at the beginning.
If the code is like this, this is the error:

```
TypeError: printsomething() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
```

If I add event to the arguments, it says:

```
NameError: name 'event' is not defined
```

Can you help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe you mean something like `lambda event: printsomething('text', event)`

Comment: By using () after your function name you are calling it. By wrapping it in a lambda you can store a function with argument as @khelwood shows in his comment. `c.tag_bind(button,'<Button-1>', lambda event: printsomething('text', event))`

Answer (score 0):

`c.tag_bind(button,'<Button-1>', printsomething('text'))` is not passing `printsomething` to `tag_bind`; it is calling `printsomething` immediately with only one argument.

You can pass a lambda function that accepts one argument and calls `printsomething` with two arguments:

```
c.tag_bind(button,'<Button-1>', lambda event: printsomething('text', event))
```

Comment: Thank you! That really helped me!

Comment: @Einstein Great. If you find and click the checkmark next to the answer you can mark it as accepted.